# Modern alternatives to Mutt

Tags: linux, osx, ubuntu, email-client

I'm after suggestions about "better" mail clients than Mutt, principally for FOSS dev.  My baseline is Mutt because I used it before and it basically does what I expect, but I'm not sure whether more recent alternatives do things "better".

My requirements:

- Talks to an IMAP server (Gmail) and probably speaks SMTP (but I'm happy to set up a local MTA if needed)
- Deals well with mailing lists—the threading support in Mutt is great, is there anything better?
- Ability to interleave quotes, my response and code—in Mutt this is basically up to me and my editor (emacs and vim when remote) but I've seen some clients use Markdown
- Can be accessed from Ubuntu and OS X

I don't have any great preference if it's a local program or web-based—but I'd prefer not to move my data off to another third-party.

Comment: Have you tried [Notmuch](http://notmuchmail.org/) with mutt? You'd get to keep your email client, but supercharge it with fast indexing tools. It's not much, but it'll definitly improve your experience. Here's the documentation page for [notmuch-mutt](http://notmuchmail.org/notmuch-mutt/)

Comment: Not used `notmuch`, but have used similar tools for indexing local mail—and I'd prefer to leave mail on an IMAP server

Comment: You haven't set any criteria that are *not* fulfilled by mutt. Why change?